# How to access specific script file in a server Powershell instance?

Tags: powershell, psexec

I have a script file `script1.ps1` that is passing an argument to another script file `script2.ps1` in a `psexec.exe` command, the problem is that when i run this file in my system, it executes perfectly, but when running it by a server, it says the file path does not exist. Here is the code

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
$path = $dir + '\Script2\script2.ps1'
$args = 1
$Query = 'psexec.exe \\' + $ip + ' /accepteula cmd /c "powershell -noninteractive -file $path -id $args"'
Invoke-Expression $Query
```

So sorry that i currently don't have screenshot of the error message, but it is saying file does not exist. I want to know is there an special way to declare a file path? I have tried this as well, `\\$computer1\C$\Folder\Script2\script2.ps1` but doesn't work, seems like i am doing something wrong in it.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists on remote system too? In addition, why use `psexec` instead of Powershell remoting?

Comment: Yes it exist, i copied the entire folder, and for a double check, i navigated to that file as well and it exist. I am using `psexec` so that i could run my `script2.ps1` on the other server IP i am trying to access. It is requirment of my task, powershell remoting isn;t getting the job done. Will appreciate your help.

Comment: The first debug step would be to use hard-coded path to the script file on remote system. If that works, you know there's a problem with the argument value or passing. If it doesn't, there's a problem with trying to execute the existing script. What's more, you don't have to get a screenshot of the error, a copypasted text would be just fine. Add that into the question, don't answer as a comment. It would be hard to read without any formatting.

Comment: [Invoke-Expression considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). Use the call operator instead: `& psexec.exe "\\$ip" /accepteula cmd /c "..."`